# Bootstrap tour 'end tour' when clicked stops the tour for good

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

I have a tour currently running on my site, but it doesn't seem to actually keep track of if the user has clicked End Tour.  Meaning that if they click it once, it ends the tour, but then when they revisit the page, the tour will automatically start again as though it's the first time they've landed on that page.

```
var tour = new Tour({
    backdrop:true,
    onEnd:function(t){
        var last = t._options.steps.length;
        if(t._current==last-1){
            $.post( "home/tourCompleted", function( data ) {});
            //$('#tourTracking').attr("step",0);
            //$("#tourTracking").addClass("hidden");
        }else{
            if(t._current==0){
                $.post( "home/setCurrentStepTour/0", function( data ) {});
                //$('#tourTracking').attr("step",0);
            }else{
                $.post( "home/setCurrentStepTour/"+t._current, function( data ) {});
                //$('#tourTracking').attr("step",t._current);
            }
        }

        if($.browser.device){
            $("#dropdownToolbar").removeClass("open4tour open");
        }

        $("html,body").css('overflow', 'auto');
        document.body.removeEventListener('touchstart',null);

    },
    onShown: function(tour) {
        var stepElement = getTourElement(tour);
        $(stepElement).after($('.tour-step-background'));
        $(stepElement).after($('.tour-backdrop'));
    }
});

function getTourElement(tour){
    return tour._options.steps[tour._current].element
}

var bookcount = <?php echo count($lstscbook)?>;

if (bookcount == 0){
    $('.tour-tour-0').addClass('noBookTour');
    tour.addSteps([
        {...}
    ]);
}else{ ... }

<?if(isset($redir4tour) && $redir4tour==TRUE){?>

    var redir4tour=true;
<?}else{?>
    var redir4tour=false;
<?}?>

if(redir4tour)window.history.pushState({},"", "<?=base_url()?>");

if(($('#tourTracking').attr("step")==0 && !(<?php echo (isset($tour['completed']) ? $tour['completed'] : "false" )?>)) || redir4tour){
    document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){ return true; });
    $("html,body").css('overflow', 'hidden');
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    tour.init();
    tour.restart(); //using restart -> https://github.com/sorich87/bootstrap-tour/issues/140
}

$("a#tourTracking").click(function(e){
    document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){ return true; });
    $("html,body").css('overflow', 'hidden');
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    var step = $('#tourTracking').attr("step");
    if($.browser.device && (step==2 || step==14 || step==19 || step==20 || step==21)){//steps in toolbar responsive. have to open toolbar before set step!
        $("#dropdownToolbar").addClass("open4tour");
        $("#responsiveToolbar").click();
    }

    window.localStorage.clear();
    tour.setCurrentStep(step);
    tour.init();
    tour.restart(); //using restart -> https://github.com/sorich87/bootstrap-tour/issues/140
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this uses window.localStorage by default for persistence. Are you clearing this with `window.localStorage.clear();` at the end?

Comment: Yeah, we have a window.localStorage.clear at the bottom, 5 lines up from it.

Comment: Does your tour persistence issue resolve if you remove this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the option: `storage: false` to disable this behavior

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this line right after the initialization of "var tour = new Tour({"

```
name: 'tourNew' + Date.now().toString(),
```

Try that and see if it works for you as well.